# Alt tab page title "animation"

Tags: html, css, tabs, title

I want to "animate" the page title in the browser tab to alternate between two states every second like this example:

1. Page Title
2. ⭐ Page title

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```js
const star = "⭐ ";

setInterval(() => {
  if (!document.title.startsWith(star))
    document.title = star + document.title;
  else 
    document.title = document.title.replace(star, '');
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to amend the whole title, I just want to add a symbol to the start of existing title. Sorry my fault for not explaining properly.

Comment: I've edited the answer. Please check if that would work for you.

Comment: I think that looks good. So would that be just like having the star appear (or flash) every second on any page? If so that's perfect!

Comment: It would have the star for 1 second, then no star for 1 second, and so on. If it works, please mark answer as accepted so others can see :D

Comment: Just testing it and it's exactly what I want. 1,000,000,000 thanks!